# Перессылка с сайта на другой сайт

Tags: joomla

Доброе время суток!
У меня вопрос, есть сайт сделанный на Joomla [ссылка на сайт](http://altyntaraz.kz/). Когда открываешь сайт, через 20-25 секунд пересылается на сайт http://algerie-service.com/ads/ ... 
Почти везде поискал в интернете, пробовал отключит JavaScript в браузере не помогло, поискал в файлах altyntaraz.kz - это слова, без результата... в .htaccesse тоже ничего не нашел( Помогите пож-та... жду

Comment: а почему вы что-то искали на этом (algerie-service.com) сайте. Проблему нужно искать на вашем сайте. У вас есть доступ к исходному коду сайта algerie-service.com?

Comment: у себя на сайте, конечно же, я искал проблему... http://altyntaraz.kz/ - на этом сайте... исходники имею.

Comment: так. Ну это как искать иголку в стоге сена. Пройдитесь grep'ом по файлам в поисках слова "Refresh".

`grep -ri 'Refresh' путь/к/корню/сайта`

Я думаю найдется много строк. Вам нужно что-то вроде:

`header("Refresh: 12; URL = $url")`

Comment: > поискал в файлах algerie-service.com

катаюсь) @KryDos +

Comment: Откорректировал вопрос) Palmervan спс)
@KryDos спасибо большое, сейчас поищу...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пути решения:

- <s>искать модификацию в js файлах</s> пардон упустил момент из топика
- искать модификацию в php ввиде eval(base64_decode('тут много букв'));
- устранять модификацию

Comment: еще здесь посмотрите обсуждение причин http://hashcode.ru/questions/192593/

правда у вас скорее всего дыра в joomla

Comment: Спасибо :) был второй вариант, реально респект вам пацаны, что быстро ответили, и помогли решит проблему))) надо будет обновить версию joomla и пароли все поменяю на более надежные.